# HTML h1 tag not displaying correctly above javascript+css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have the following code (from a code pen fork), and wish to add a simple Html H1 tag above the animation on the page. I have tried the below, but for some reason the H1 tag just displays for a second (flashes) and then disappears off the screen.

I have tried placing it in several places and also used 
 tags, but the same thing happens.

Can someone please suggest a fix and also explain why this is occuring?

**html, javascript file:** and **CSS File (style.css)**

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(element, ctx, w, h) {
    this.element = element
    this.ctx = ctx
    this.width = w
    this.height = h

    this.interactive = false
    this.playing = true

    this.point = {
      value: 150,
      speed: 0.25,
      limit: 70,
      floor: 10,
      up: true,
      animating: false
    }

    this.multiplier = {
      value: 1,
      speed: 0.005,
      limit: 20,
      floor: 1,
      up: true,
      animating: true
    }

    this.center = {
      x: w / 2,
      y: h / 2,
      targetX: w / 2,
      targetY: h / 2,
      easing: 0.02
    }

    this.radius = {
      val: h / 2.2,
      targetVal: h / 2.2,
      easing: 0.02
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this))
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move.bind(this))
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyup.bind(this))

    this.hue = 160
  }

  click(e) {
    this.interactive = !this.interactive

    if (!this.interactive) {
      this.center.targetX = this.width / 2
      this.center.targetY = this.height / 2
      this.radius.targetVal = this.height / 2.2

      this.element.classList.remove('interactive')
    } else {
      this.element.classList.add('interactive')
    }
  }

  move(e) {
    if (!this.interactive) {
      return
    }

    const h3 = this.height / 3

    this.center.targetX = e.pageX
    this.center.targetY = Math.max(e.pageY, h3)

    this.radius.targetVal = h3 + (e.pageY * 0.8)
  }

  keyup(e) {
    if (e.which != 32) {
      return
    }

    this.playing = !this.playing

    if (this.playing && this.drawLoop) {
      this.drawLoop()
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.clear()

    this.animate(this.point)
    this.animate(this.multiplier)
    this.ease(this.center)
    this.ease(this.radius)

    this.hue += 0.3

    const h = (this.hue % 360)

    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + h + ',70%,20%)'
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ',80%,60%,0.2)'
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
  }

  clear() {
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    this.ctx.fill()
  }

  draw() {
    let radius = this.radius.val

    const w2 = this.center.x,
      h2 = this.center.y

    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.shadowBlur = 0
    this.ctx.shadowColor = 'black'

    const points = this.point.value
    const multiplier = this.multiplier.value

    for (let p = 0; p < points; p++) {
      const t = (p / points) * Math.PI * 2
      const t2 = ((p * multiplier) / points) * Math.PI * 2
      const x = radius * Math.cos(t) + w2
      const y = radius * Math.sin(t) + h2
      const x2 = radius * Math.cos(t2) + w2
      const y2 = radius * Math.sin(t2) + h2

      this.ctx.moveTo(x, y)
      this.ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    }

    this.ctx.arc(w2, h2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)

    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
  }

  animate(object) {
    if (!object.animating) {
      return
    }

    if (object.up) {
      object.value += object.speed
    } else {
      object.value -= object.speed
    }

    if (object.value > object.limit) {
      object.up = false
    } else if (object.value < object.floor) {
      object.up = true
    }
  }

  ease(object) {
    if (object.val) {
      const dv = object.targetVal - object.val
      object.val += dv * object.easing

      return
    }

    const dx = object.targetX - object.x
    const dy = object.targetY - object.y
    object.x += dx * object.easing
    object.y += dy * object.easing
  }

  random(from, to) {
    return from + (Math.rand() * (to - from))
  }

  resize(w, h) {
    this.width = w
    this.height = h
    this.center.targetX = w / 2
    this.center.targetY = h / 2

    this.radius.targetVal = h / 2.2
  }
}

(_ => {
  const canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d')

  let w = canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight,
    density = 1

  const canvas = new Canvas(canvasElement, ctx, w, h)

  function setup() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize)

    density = window.devicePixelRatio != undefined ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1.0

    canvasElement.width = w * density
    canvasElement.height = h * density

    canvas.width = w
    canvas.height = h
    canvas.drawLoop = draw

    ctx.scale(density, density)

    draw()
  }

  function draw() {
    canvas.update()
    canvas.draw()

    if (canvas.playing) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    }
  }

  function resize() {
    w = canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth
    h = canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight

    canvasElement.width = w * density
    canvasElement.height = h * density

    canvas.resize(w, h)

    ctx.scale(density, density)
  }

  setup()
})()
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

canvas.interactive {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <center>
    <h1>
      <font color="white">This is the H1 Tag</font>
    </h1>
  </center>
</head>

<body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Update**

Thanks to the answer below, I have changed the css to the following, and the tag does display, but the animation is not centered. How can the canvas be re-positioned so that other 'elements' or objects can be fit around it?

```
canvas {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: you h1 is inside the head tag

Comment: Temani - as mentioned, I have already tried putting in the body,and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `canvas` style is set to take up the whole page. Your `h1` is also inside the `head` of the document.  So that needs moved into the `body` too.

```
canvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

If you remove the `canvas` style, your `h1` will sit above the canvas.

**Edit:**
Reading between the lines OP wants the image scaled down and centered.  I've created a Fiddle to show how this can be achieved.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw0ssfhx/)

Comment: This is useful, thank you but is there a way I can simply re-position the canvas as opposed to move it? For instance, position the canvas and the animation to play in the centre of the screen, and of course have the H1 tag at the top center.

Comment: If I look at the commented out `canvas` in browser, it shows the `h1` then the canvas which is centered.  nothing has actually moved, aside from the code from your `head` to `body`.

Comment: Your way requires me to remove the canvas style. As answered by answer below, I wish to KEEP the canvas, and re-position it. What is the purpose of the canvas if it is not used? Unless you can give me a good reason for not using the canvas all together. Also note, that if I remove the canvas, won't the canvas interactivity for the animation fail to work as well?

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. I am not suggesting you remove the **canvas**, I'm suggesting you remove the style from it.  Take the `canvas` **style** out of your stylesheet and you'll see what I mean.  The canvas will remain, it simply won't be absolutely positioned with a height and width of 100%.

Comment: @MissComputing check my updated answer - I've created a fiddle for you after reading your other comments on answers.  Let me know if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Add some `z-index` to your `h1` and remove the obsolete tags:

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(element, ctx, w, h) {
    this.element = element
    this.ctx = ctx
    this.width = w
    this.height = h

    this.interactive = false
    this.playing = true

    this.point = {
      value: 150,
      speed: 0.25,
      limit: 70,
      floor: 10,
      up: true,
      animating: false
    }

    this.multiplier = {
      value: 1,
      speed: 0.005,
      limit: 20,
      floor: 1,
      up: true,
      animating: true
    }

    this.center = {
      x: w / 2,
      y: h / 2,
      targetX: w / 2,
      targetY: h / 2,
      easing: 0.02
    }

    this.radius = {
      val: h / 2.2,
      targetVal: h / 2.2,
      easing: 0.02
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this))
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move.bind(this))
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyup.bind(this))

    this.hue = 160
  }

  click(e) {
    this.interactive = !this.interactive

    if (!this.interactive) {
      this.center.targetX = this.width / 2
      this.center.targetY = this.height / 2
      this.radius.targetVal = this.height / 2.2

      this.element.classList.remove('interactive')
    } else {
      this.element.classList.add('interactive')
    }
  }

  move(e) {
    if (!this.interactive) {
      return
    }

    const h3 = this.height / 3

    this.center.targetX = e.pageX
    this.center.targetY = Math.max(e.pageY, h3)

    this.radius.targetVal = h3 + (e.pageY * 0.8)
  }

  keyup(e) {
    if (e.which != 32) {
      return
    }

    this.playing = !this.playing

    if (this.playing && this.drawLoop) {
      this.drawLoop()
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.clear()

    this.animate(this.point)
    this.animate(this.multiplier)
    this.ease(this.center)
    this.ease(this.radius)

    this.hue += 0.3

    const h = (this.hue % 360)

    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + h + ',70%,20%)'
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + h + ',80%,60%,0.2)'
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
  }

  clear() {
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    this.ctx.fill()
  }

  draw() {
    let radius = this.radius.val

    const w2 = this.center.x,
      h2 = this.center.y

    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.shadowBlur = 0
    this.ctx.shadowColor = 'black'

    const points = this.point.value
    const multiplier = this.multiplier.value

    for (let p = 0; p < points; p++) {
      const t = (p / points) * Math.PI * 2
      const t2 = ((p * multiplier) / points) * Math.PI * 2
      const x = radius * Math.cos(t) + w2
      const y = radius * Math.sin(t) + h2
      const x2 = radius * Math.cos(t2) + w2
      const y2 = radius * Math.sin(t2) + h2

      this.ctx.moveTo(x, y)
      this.ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    }

    this.ctx.arc(w2, h2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)

    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.closePath()
  }

  animate(object) {
    if (!object.animating) {
      return
    }

    if (object.up) {
      object.value += object.speed
    } else {
      object.value -= object.speed
    }

    if (object.value > object.limit) {
      object.up = false
    } else if (object.value < object.floor) {
      object.up = true
    }
  }

  ease(object) {
    if (object.val) {
      const dv = object.targetVal - object.val
      object.val += dv * object.easing

      return
    }

    const dx = object.targetX - object.x
    const dy = object.targetY - object.y
    object.x += dx * object.easing
    object.y += dy * object.easing
  }

  random(from, to) {
    return from + (Math.rand() * (to - from))
  }

  resize(w, h) {
    this.width = w
    this.height = h
    this.center.targetX = w / 2
    this.center.targetY = h / 2

    this.radius.targetVal = h / 2.2
  }
}

(_ => {
  const canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d')

  let w = canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight,
    density = 1

  const canvas = new Canvas(canvasElement, ctx, w, h)

  function setup() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize)

    density = window.devicePixelRatio != undefined ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1.0

    canvasElement.width = w * density
    canvasElement.height = h * density

    canvas.width = w
    canvas.height = h
    canvas.drawLoop = draw

    ctx.scale(density, density)

    draw()
  }

  function draw() {
    canvas.update()
    canvas.draw()

    if (canvas.playing) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    }
  }

  function resize() {
    w = canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth
    h = canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight

    canvasElement.width = w * density
    canvasElement.height = h * density

    canvas.resize(w, h)

    ctx.scale(density, density)
  }

  setup()
})()
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

canvas.interactive {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<h1>This is a title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your canvas styles. If you add a margin-top to your canvas the h1 will not be removed, try it like this:

```
canvas {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

You'll see that now your `h1` is not `dissapearing` anymore.

**Edit**

Reading between the lines OP appears to want it scaled down and centered, so I've created a fiddle with updated code.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw0ssfhx/)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried margin-top which does work, but when I reduce the width and height, it does not center. I tried position: absolute for centering which didn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: In that case you'll need to use a parent div:

```HTML
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

and CSS it like this:
```CSS
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
canvas {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```